# Shopify Infinite Scroll With Product.Loop

Tags: scroll, shopify, infinite, forever

Alright.  So I am trying to get this following script to work with infinite scroll on shopify.

http://www.davecap.com/post/9675189741/infinite-scroll-for-shopify-collections

The problem is I have a special version in my theme called product.loop which calls the products it seems to be a different way.

To start they say to edit collections.liquid to be

```
{% paginate collection.products by 20 %} 
<!-- the top of your collections.liquid --> 

<!-- START PRODUCTS --> 
{% for product in collection.products %} 
<!-- START PRODUCT {{ forloop.index | plus:paginate.current_offset }} -->
<div class="product" id="product-{{ forloop.index | plus:paginate.current_offset }}"> {% include 'product' with product %} </div>
<!-- END PRODUCT {{ forloop.index | plus:paginate.current_offset }} --> 
{% endfor %}

{% if paginate.next %}
<div id="more">
  <p>&darr; <a href="{{ paginate.next.url }}">More</a></p>
</div>
{% endif %}
<div id="product-list-foot"></div>
<!-- END PRODUCTS --> 

<!-- the bottom of your collections.liquid --> 
{% endpaginate %}
```

My collections.liquid is as follows

```
<div class="{% if settings.show_sidebar %}span9{% else %}span12{% endif %} columns">
    {% paginate collection.products by settings.pagination_limit %}
    <h1 class="title">{{ collection.title }}</h1>
    <hr>
    {{ collection.description }}
    {% unless collection.description == '' %}
    <hr>
    {% endunless %}
    {% if collection.products.size == 0 %}
        {{ 'collection.no_products' | t }}
    {% else %}
        <!-- TAGS -->
        {% include 'tags-snippet' %}
        <!-- PRODUCT COLLECTION -->
        {% assign col_group = collection %}
        {% assign col_settings = settings.product_collection_columns %}
        {% include 'product-loop' %}
    {% endif %}
        {% include 'pagination' %}
    {% endpaginate %}
</div>


<div class="{% if settings.show_sidebar %}span9{% else %}span12{% endif %} columns">
    {% paginate collection.products by settings.pagination_limit %}
    <h1 class="title">{{ collection.title }}</h1>
    <hr>
    {{ collection.description }}
    {% unless collection.description == '' %}
    <hr>
    {% endunless %}
    {% if collection.products.size == 0 %}
        {{ 'collection.no_products' | t }}
    {% else %}
        <!-- TAGS -->
        {% include 'tags-snippet' %}
        <!-- PRODUCT COLLECTION -->
        {% assign col_group = collection %}
        {% assign col_settings = settings.product_collection_columns %}
        {% include 'product-loop' %}
    {% endif %}
        {% include 'pagination' %}
    {% endpaginate %}
</div>
```

Next I created a theme.liquid.js file and here is the following code

```
 {% if template contains 'collection' %}
         function ScrollExecute() {
           if($(document).height() - 800 < ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
               scrollNode = $('#more').last();    
               scrollURL = $('#more p a').last().attr("href");
               if(scrollNode.length > 0 && scrollNode.css('display') != 'none') {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: 'GET',
                       url: scrollURL,
                       beforeSend: function() {
                           scrollNode.clone().empty().insertAfter(scrollNode).append('<img src=\"{{ "loading.gif" | asset_url }}\" />');
                           scrollNode.hide();
                       },
                       success: function(data) {
                           // remove loading feedback
                           scrollNode.next().remove();
                           var filteredData = $(data).find(".product");
                           filteredData.insertBefore( $("#product-list-foot") );                   
                       },
                       dataType: "html"
                   });
               }
           }
         }

         $(document).ready(function () {
           $(window).scroll(function(){
               $.doTimeout( 'scroll', 200, ScrollExecute);
           });
         });
    {% endif %}
```

Finally I added the dottimeout script as instructed http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/docs/files/jquery-ba-dotimeout-js.html and added to my theme.liquid file

```
{% if template contains 'collection' %}
     function ScrollExecute() {
       if($(document).height() - 800 < ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
           scrollNode = $('#more').last();    
           scrollURL = $('#more p a').last().attr("href");
           if(scrollNode.length > 0 && scrollNode.css('display') != 'none') {
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: scrollURL,
                   beforeSend: function() {
                       scrollNode.clone().empty().insertAfter(scrollNode).append('<img src=\"{{ "loading.gif" | asset_url }}\" />');
                       scrollNode.hide();
                   },
                   success: function(data) {
                       // remove loading feedback
                       scrollNode.next().remove();
                       var filteredData = $(data).find(".product");
                       filteredData.insertBefore( $("#product-list-foot") );                   
                   },
                   dataType: "html"
               });
           }
       }
     }

     $(document).ready(function () {
       $(window).scroll(function(){
           $.doTimeout( 'scroll', 200, ScrollExecute);
       });
     });
{% endif %}
```

So I know the problem is going to be with my product loop page which is

```
<div id="collection">
    {% if col_group.products.size > 0 %}
        {% for product in col_group.products %}
        {% if col_settings == '3' %}
            {% cycle 'product-loop-clear-start-2': '<div class="row-fluid"><ul class="thumbnails">', '', '' %}
        {% elsif col_settings == '4' %}
            {% cycle 'product-loop-clear-start-2': '<div class="row-fluid"><ul class="thumbnails">', '', '', '' %}
        {% endif %}

            <li class="span{% if col_settings == '4' %}3{% elsif col_settings == '3' %}4{% endif %} {% for collection in product.collections %}{{ collection.title }} {% endfor %}">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="bl center rel" href= "{{ product.url | within: col_group }}" title="{{ product.title }}">
                        <img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}">
                        {% if product.available %}
                            {% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
                            <span class="{{ settings.sale_icon }} abs">{{ 'product.product_loop.on_sale' | t }}</span>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                            <span class="label abs">{{ 'product.product_loop.out_of_stock' | t }}</span>
                        {% endif %}
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4><a href= "{{ product.url | within: col_group }}" title="{{ product.title }}">{{ product.title }}</a></h4>
                        <p>
                            {% if product.price_varies %}{{ 'product.product_loop.price_varies' | t }}{% endif %}{{ product.price_min | money_with_currency }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% if forloop.last %}
        </ul>
        </div>
        {% else %}
            {% if col_settings == '3' %}
                {% cycle 'product-loop-clear-end-2': '', '', '</ul></div>' %}
            {% elsif col_settings == '4' %}
                {% cycle 'product-loop-clear-end-2': '', '', '', '</ul></div>' %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p class="alert">{{ product.product_loop.empty_collection_alert }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

So after adding the scripts in the proper places and editing the collection.liquid to be

```
{% include 'product-loop' with product %}
```

In an attempt call product loop.  I am still getting

```
 Liquid error: Could not find asset snippets/product.liquid
```

I tried contacting the plugin creator, but he did not have time, tried posting in other forums but they seem rather lackluster in terms of replies.  SO I am looking for advice from the awesome stackoverflow community.  Plus i have seen this problem for others online with no fixes found just yet.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: In your first code block there is `{% include 'product' with product %}` that is looking for a snippet called `product.liquid`, presumably containing markup for your product grid item, which is missing from your theme.